# Why do the graphics differ so much between NFS Hot Pursuit and NFS World?

Tags: version-differences, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

I tried both of that games and I'm shocked a bit. These games appeared almost at the same time but the graphics in NFS World is incomparable even with that in NFS Carbon (enough said about cool graphics in NFS Hot Pursuit). I can understand that in NFS World there is more freedom etc. so it's easier to handle NFS Hot Pursuit, but again - in NFS Carbon the city was quite big and the graphics was better.

Maybe I do not understand something and there are some secret setting for the graphics - but can anybody tell why graphics in NFS World is such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NFS World is MMORG (Massive Multiplayer Online Racing Game) and therefore it has a different target from the other two.

It is quite common for multiplayer online games to have "light" graphics because, in order to generate profit, it has to run smoothly on most hardware configuration worldwide available (consider also Asia). In addition NFS World was [first announced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_World) to be free-to-play and I imagine that the budget planned was not big enough to allow developers create a powerful engine that matches also the infrastructure requirements of a MMORG.

Comment: @Ilya - If Drake's answer helped you can 'accept' the answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :)